# get description of an installed package without actual importing it

Tags: python

If you type this:

```
import somemodule
help(somemodule)
```

it will print out paged package description. I would need to get the same description as a string but without importing this package to the current namespace. Is this possible? It surely is, because anything is possible in Python, but what is the most elegant/pythonic way of doing so?

Side note: by elegant way I mean without opening a separate process and capturing its stdout... ;)

In other words, is there a way to peek into a unimported but installed package and get its description? Maybe something with `importlib.abc.InspectLoader`? But I have no idea how to make it work the way I need.

UPDATE: I need not just not polluting the namespace but also do this without leaving any traces of itself or dependent modules in memory and in `sys.modules` etc. Like it was never really imported.

UPDATE: Before anyone asks me why I need it - I want to list all installed python packages with their description. But after this I do not want to have them imported in `sys.modules` nor occupying excessive space in memory because there can be a lots of them.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. That makes it possible

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you will need to import the module to get a help string is that in many cases, the help strings are actually generated in code. It would be pointlessly difficult to parse the text of such a package to get the string since you would then have to write a small Python interpreter to reconstruct the actual string.

That being said, there are ways of completely deleting a temporarily imported modules based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/487718/2988730), which summarizes a thread that appeared on the Python mailing list around 2003: http://web.archive.org/web/20080926094551/http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2003-December/241654.html. The methods described here will generally only work if the module is not referenced elsewhere. Otherwise the module will be unloaded in the sense that `import` will reload it from scratch instead of using the existing `sys.modules` entry, but the module will still live in memory.

Here is a function that does approximately what you want and even prints a warning if the module does not appear to have been unloaded. Unlike the solutions proposed in the linked answer, this function really handles all the side-effects of loading a module, including the fact that importing one package may import other external packages into `sys.modules`:

```
import sys, warnings
def get_help(module_name):
    modules_copy = sys.modules.copy()
    module = __import__(module_name)
    h = help(module)
    for modname in list(sys.modules):
        if modname not in modules_copy:
            del sys[modname]
    if sys.getrefcount(module) > 1:
        warnings.warn('Module {} is likely not to be completely wiped'.format(module_name))
    del module
    return h
```

The reason that I make a list of the keys in the final loop is that it is inadvisable to modify a dictionary (or any other iterable) as you iterate through it. At least in Python 3, `dict.keys()` returns an iterable that is backed by the dictionary itself, not a frozen copy. I am not sure if `h = ...` and `return h` are even necessary, but in the worst case, `h` is just `None`.

Comment: Thanks a log, I am going to give it a try. But still it feels a bit fragile. Therefore I tend to use a separate process for importing the modules, piping back the required strings and then removing this process(es). This seems error proof and moreover I will not block my main process while acquiring the data, which I assume will take a while.

Comment: your way is indeed more reliable. You should post your own answer. Also, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42142660/2988730) came from writing the answer above.

Comment: I am going to post my answer once I get the solution working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are only worried about keeping the global namespace tidy, you could always import in a function:

```
>>> def get_help():
...     import math
...     help(math)
...
>>> math
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'math' is not defined
```

Comment: Trouble is that it remains loaded in memory and in `sys.modules`. I was not clear about this so I will update the question.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest a different approach, if i understand you correctly, you wish to read a portion of a package, without importing it (even within a function with local scope). I would suggest a method to do so would be via accessing the (python_path)/Lib/site-packages/(package_name)/ and reading the contents of the respective files as an alternative to importing the module so Python can.

Comment: This will work sometimes, but a lot of Python docstrings are generated with anything from a formatting expression to a wholly different piece of code setting the `__doc__` attribute. In those cases, you will end up re-implementing the interpreter just to get the doc-string.