# Python swapping out sys.modules does not work as intuited

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I was experimenting with setting the dictionary `sys.modules` while working on an answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42134260/2988730) and came across something interesting. The linked question deals with removing all the effects of importing a module. Based on [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/487718/2988730), I came up with the idea of deleting all new modules from `sys.modules` after an import. My initial implementation was to do the following (testing with `numpy` as the module to load and unload):

```
# Load the module
import sys
mod_copy = sys.modules.copy()
print('numpy' in mod_copy, 'numpy' in sys.modules) # False False
import numpy
print('numpy' in mod_copy, 'numpy' in sys.modules) # False True
print(id(numpy)) # 45138472
```

The printouts show that numpy was imported successfully and that the shallow copy does not contain it, as expected.

Now my idea was to unload the module by swapping `mod_copy` back into `sys.modules`, then delete the local reference to the module. That should in theory remove all references to it (and possibly it does):

```
sys.modules = mod_copy
del numpy
print('numpy' in sys.modules) # False
```

This should be enough to be able to re-import the module, but when I do

```
import numpy
print('numpy' in sys.modules) # False
print(id(numpy)) # 45138472
```

It appears that the numpy module is not reloaded since it has the same `id` as before. It does not show up in `sys.modules`, despite the fact that the `import` statement raises no errors and appears to complete successfully (i.e., a `numpy` module exists in the local namespace).

On the other hand, the implementation that I made in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42139290/2988730) to the linked question does appear to work fine. It modifies the dictionary directly instead of swapping it out:

```
import sys
mod_copy = sys.modules.copy()
print('numpy' in mod_copy, 'numpy' in sys.modules) # False False
import numpy
print('numpy' in mod_copy, 'numpy' in sys.modules) # False True
print(id(numpy)) # 35963432

for m in list(sys.modules):
    if m not in mod_copy:
        del sys.modules[m]
del numpy
print('numpy' in sys.modules) # False

import numpy
print('numpy' in sys.modules) # True
print(id(numpy)) # (54941000 != 35963432)
```

I am using Python 3.5.2 on an Anaconda install. I am most interested in explanations focusing on Python 3, but I am curious about Python 2.7+ as well.

The only thing I can think of that is happening here is that `sys` maintains another reference to `sys.modules` and uses that internal reference regardless of what I do to the public one. I am not sure that this covers everything though, so I would like to know what is really going on.

Comment: On Python 2, I would expect the import machinery to use its own internal reference to the module cache, independent of the `sys.modules` reference, but as far as I can tell, on Python 3.5, the [import machinery](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py) accesses the `modules` attribute of the `sys` module object whenever it needs the module cache. I don't know why `'numpy'` would fail to show up in `sys.modules` after replacing the dict and re-`import`ing `numpy`.

Comment: @user2357112. Well, it looks like there is some internal reference because the `id` of `numpy` is identical after both imports. As if it is using the original `modules` dictionary and ignoring the one that was swapped in.

Comment: The `id` being the same doesn't mean much; it's quite common for different objects to have the same ID if they have non-overlapping lifetimes. To see whether it's using the same object, you'd want to set something like `numpy.lookatme = 3` and see if that modification still shows up afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even in Python 3.5, part of the import implementation is [still written in C](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Python/import.c), and that part uses `PyThreadState_GET()->interp->modules` to retrieve the module cache, rather than going through the `sys.modules` attribute. Your import is finding `numpy` in the old `sys.modules` through one of those code paths.

`sys.modules` isn't designed to be replaced. The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules) mention that replacing it may behave unexpectedly:

> This can be manipulated to force reloading of modules and other tricks. However, **replacing the dictionary will not necessarily work as expected** and deleting essential items from the dictionary may cause Python to fail.

Comment: That makes sense. So basically there is more than one reference to the dictionary floating around. Do you think this merits a mention on the mailing list or as a bug report?

Comment: Also, does the behavior change in 3.6?

Comment: @MadPhysicist: The code looks pretty much the same on Python 3.6, but I didn't test it. As for a bug report, no. You're not expected to be able to replace the module cache. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules): "This can be manipulated to force reloading of modules and other tricks. However, **replacing the dictionary will not necessarily work as expected** and deleting essential items from the dictionary may cause Python to fail."